# VBA Form , A Selection from combobox should view the description in a text box

Tags: excel, vba, forms, combobox, offset

I have a combobox sheet where i have some data to populate the combobox by the dynamic name range , but I'm stuck with textbox to get the value right in the front cell , idk what to use , offset or index and match , can someone help me out with this?

So I have that form and I have a combobox_cars that populated by the sheet named combobox.
Then I have the textbox_power to get the offset value once I do the selection in my combox
So basically textbox will have to just display the horse power of the chosen car in the combobox.
Idk how can be reached ,by offset or by index n match ?

Will be really thankful if someone can help me with this offset or index thing to get the horsepower of a car.

I'll add the screens to proper understanding
The sheet is combobox.
The userform with combobox n textbox.
And the Vb code that i can populate the combobox with.
Thanks!!

Here is the sheet combox

```
Cars    power
BMW     550hp
Benz    400hp
Cupra   300hp
Seat    250hp
VW      450hp
```

I populated the combobox with the cars name
But on selection I want that the relevant power of the car should display in the textbox.

Comment: Are your controls (combobox, textbox) part of a Userform or are they placed directly on a sheet?

Comment: Thank ur for a answering!! , they r in a userform , basically my userform has one combobox and one textbox

Comment: I already filled the combobox with the values from the sheet , so if I select bmw in the combobox,  in the textbox "500hp" should be displayed

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an event routine in the code-behind module of the userform: In the form editor, double-click on the combobox: It will create a routine in your code that is triggered at the `Change`-event.

All the values that are displayed in the combobox are available with the property `List`, the data is stored in a 2-dimensional array (1st index is the row number, 2nd index the column number). Note that both dimensions are 0-based.

You can access the number of the selected row with the property `ListIndex`

Assuming that the combobox has the name `ComboBox1` and the textbox the name `TextBox1`, the code would look like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    With Me.ComboBox1
        Me.TextBox1.Value = .List(.ListIndex, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

N.B. Just an advice: Don't name your sheet `Combobox`, this leads only to confusion. The sheet is not a combobox. Name it `ListOfCars` or `CarLookup` or something the like.

**Update**: This works of course only if the data of the 2nd column ("HP") is part of the combobox. Assuming that you are using `RowSource` to fill the combobox:

- Add the 2nd column to the RowSource-Range, eg `combobox!A2:B10` (assuming that the sheet with your data is still named `combobox`
- Set `ColumnCount` of the combobox to 2. If you now run the form, you will see the HP information in the combobox.
- If you don't want to see the HP in the combobox, set the columnwidth for the 2nd column to 0.

[image]

**Update 2**: If you fill the combobox manually, you just need to add 1 line to your code to fill the 2nd column - you can simply write to the 2-dimensional array `List`. I assume your code looks somewhat like this

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combobox")
With Me.ComboBox1
    .Clear
    Dim row As Long
    For row = 2 To 10
        .AddItem ws.Cells(row, 1)
        ' Now add the value for the 2nd column:
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(row, 2)
    Next row
End With
```

Comment: I read ur comment and tried to apply the code u wrote , but unfortunately it's not working , it doesn't display any value in the textbox1 , but if I change Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    With Me.ComboBox1
        Me.TextBox1.Value = .List(.ListIndex, 0) ' if I change here the 1 with the 0 the cars name r displayed , but if I change to one it doesn't display anything 
    End With
End Sub

Comment: What could be the possible reason that it shows the cars name but doesn't show the power?  Maybe I am making mistake somewhere

Comment: Is the power really the 2nd column in your data? And how many columns does the combobox display?

Comment: Yes , the power is in the 2nd column so the whole column B , what do u mean by how many columns the combobox display?

Comment: Combobox display only 1 column bcuz when I filled the combobox with the dynamic range , I just set it to get the cars name columns only.

Comment: Ah, that explains the reason you get only empty values, they need to be part of the combobox. See my update

Comment: I can totally understand ur way to fill the combobox with 2 column n not to show the second one , but the thing is I'm not populating my combobox with Rowsourse , I'm doin it im the VBA editor under Userform_initialize() , with for loop , so I'm not using Rowsource , but I appreciate that u showed me that way too , still my problem is not solved.

Comment: You can also fill the 2nd column manually, see my update 2.

Comment: Okay I tried to put the code as u said n even modified the userform , especially the combobox the column n width , I have to say it worked that way , but but now whenever I select a car name , it just giving me only 1 power from the second column,  like if I select bmw it should give me 500hp but its giving me 300hp , and if I select seat still its giving me 300hp

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help you any further, you need to figure out what's going wrong. Make the 2nd column visible (set the width to something larger than 0pt and check if the data is correct. Check with the debugger if the event routine is triggered. Check with the debugger the value that is written into the text box. Is there any event routine for the text box that overwrites the value...

Comment: I appreciate the effort u made to make me understand things n helped me out with this offset stuff , thank u !! , and yeah now I'll try to figure out why the values r not right , but will see how to adjust this , so far ur coding made me progress n helped understanding things,  again thank u! , I guess I will have more new questions so I'll ask em , feel free to answer if u want to.